# Node.js server on local Natted network

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nat

I've developed a node.js application while I was in holiday and I was using a not natted wifi connection. Now that I'm back home with my natted wifi I'm not able to access my node js server through the localhost from my phone. I tried accessing it from the local IP but still my server didn't see any connection... Any suggestions?

I'm using socket connections with express and I'm using the 3000 port. I'm on arch linux.

Comment: There is too little information in your question  and too many variables in your network setup to answer your question -- and since it is about networking and not programming it does not belong on stackoverflow but on one one of the other stackexchange sites that deals specifically with networking

Comment: is your phone and computer on the same network?

Comment: of course are on the same network... However sorry if is not the appropriate forum.